# Background Email Process in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Currently I am doing one project, where this mail sending process takes too much time.

The code which I have written in that project first sends a mail and after that it redirects to the next step, but it takes too much time. So now I want to redirect it to another page and in background I want to do this email process.

Is it possible to send Email in background classic ASP?

Comment: There's likely real issues with your code if one e-mail takes *"too much time"*, but until you show us some we can't suggest ways to make it more efficient.

Comment: classic asp doesn't have native queue support but you should check out MSMQ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @cfreear MSMQ is just the queuing mechanism like RabbitMQ and others, but you would still need something to consume that queue regardless of what you use.

Comment: I think before we start recommending queuing / 3rd party solutions the OP needs to explain why the process takes so long for one e-mail, that is issue here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform multithreading/background process in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952895/how-to-perform-multithreading-background-process-in-classic-asp)

Comment: Here I am sending one mail but includes many people in CC.                  
I need to send mail to different responsible person Like If Currently I am on first step so I need to fetch who are the responsible users for the next process.  
The same way it also fetches Admin users, and marks them in CC.      
It also fetch who has raised this request from the database and includes that user in CC.

Comment: In my code when user approves from first tab it saves all data in database ,after that it fetches who are responsible users for next tab+ admin+ requested user and after that mail code is triggered. currently user has to wait untill it data is saved in the databse and mail triggered. But i want to redirect to user on another page after the data is saved and in backgroung mail should be trigerred.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can not easily run a thread in classic ASP, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538065/can-we-create-threads-in-classic-asp) f.i.

As [Tom Baires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546375/911635) answer suggests, you can store the .eml as file on the web server, so the ASP file would finish shortly. You'd have to build a background task that searches for these files to sends them asynchronously.

**EDIT:** as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952895/how-to-perform-multithreading-background-process-in-classic-asp), storing the details in a DB queue would be better than saving files.

Another option would be to handle e-mail sending on a different page, sending the needed parameters as AJAX request. Note that you are dependent on the client browser to finish the request.

Neither of these is an out-of-the-box solution, but I hope the explanation is understandable for you to find a solution.

Comment: Like you say there is no *"out-of-the-box"* solution but there are 101 ways you can do this, saving an EML file to server wouldn't be my first choice. The second suggestion would be one I would consider but running the XHR request from the server *(fire and forget)* and continue on then something else a service / agent handles the issued request on a batch basis.

Comment: This is exactly what the first option describes, a service/agent that sends the saved .eml files. Maybe I shouldn't have referenced @Tom's answer, because he could have meant something different.

Comment: Storing any files tot he server is just overkill especially for something like an e-mail that is sent and forgotten about. Ideally you want something that  stores the details in a database / queuing mechanism *(like MSMQ)* and then the service / agent pulls the information and processes it. See [A: How to perform multithreading/background process in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952956/692942).

Comment: Agreed and updated. I only saw the dupe after having posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions

1) EML File
Save the mail as a .eml file in a folder and a other service send the mail for you. http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/queue

2) Email Transaction Service
Use a email Transaction Service for sending your mails.
https://sendgrid.com/ or https://www.mandrill.com/

Comment: **@Tom Baires** I am working on classic asp not  on .NET.Is this .eml concept works for classic asp?